# What is the best way to deliver django project as a full installation file (setup.exe) to be user-friendly and not revealing your whole scripts?

Tags: python, django, docker, installation

I have a django project which is working fine. However, this question can be related to any django project.
Django works in a way that after running `python manage.py runserver` the project is accessible at `localhost:8000`. But when you deliver the project to the customer you cannot expect them to open command windows every time, then run `python manage.py runserver`, then open a browser, then type `localhost:8000` and etc.
I have heard `docker` might be a solution to this. But docker will need the scripts available in the local machine. I am talking about making a full installation file like when you buy a video game and the scripts are not accessible easily (seems there are binary files).

The real question is how can we protect our code and scripts and be sure they cannot be accessed easily after we have installed them in a customer's computer?

**Edit:** My client is the service provider who will host the project for its own clients. That is why I am seeking to deliver the project in a way that is at least different from just copying and pasting everything.

Comment: Why are you shipping a django server to your client? If you want to provide a service, you can host it - or if you don't want to do that, make an application using something like qt - that can be packaged as an exe.

Comment: My client is the service provider who will host the project for its own clients. That is why I am seeking to deliver the project in a way that is at least different from just copying and pasting everything.

Comment: In any case, neither you nor your clients should be running a production server with `runserver`, nor should they be accessing it via port 8000.

Comment: But if your client is a "service provider", they should have the capability of running a web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to create a docker image as suggested here then whoever needs to run it on local computer or as website application can freely just run a docker image locally or deploy it as docker image.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/

Comment: That would indeed be the easiest solution, but the you would still need the project files/source code to spin up the container.

Comment: @MdaEngineer After creating the docker image, are the projects source files required to be present in the system? Or docker has some way of compressing them or converting them to other formats that are not flat script files?

Comment: @Mike you can create a dockerfile which tells docker what to wrap up into the docker image by using commands COPY .

Comment: @MdaEngineer I guess I wont find a better solution than docker on this one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Django is webdevelopment framework. So it enables you to make web applications, not native apps (like the video games you've mentioned).

Once you feel you have a releasable product (build with django) and you would like your customers to acces your django website/application you should deploy it to a public server/host. That way your customers only need to open there browsers and go to your application.

You can do this a 100 different ways with a 1000 different setups, depending on the usage and complexity of your (web)application. To do this you need to know a little bit about system administration. There are a ton of tutorials online on how to deploy django projects.

Most **important** for you to learn is that you build a webapplications with Django wich can be taken in production by publishing it on the web and not by downloading some .exe file.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of all of that. But doesn't answer my question, because my customer is actually the service provider who will host the project for its own clients and requires the the django project to be on their system. Since they have some developers on their team too, I am afraid all my effort, algorithms and ideas are going to be stolen by some. I am looking for a way for that to not happen at least like a piece of cake.

Comment: Oke. If your customer wants to host this project on premise (or in the cloud) it will need the projects source code anyway. The only way they can use the application and not have acces to it's code is if you handle the hosting your self and let them acces the hosting server only for usage of the application.

Comment: I myself also doubted there would be a solution. Because one way or the other any professional developer can crack the code eventually. I was just hoping there was a way so I could tell myself I have done something to prevent the code to be revealed easily.